# Using material-ui in client-side requireJS environment?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, amd, material-ui

I've been researching for a couple hours now on how to include `material-ui` as a client-side AMD module for my application, and here is the closest I've come. Using [`grunt-amd-wrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-amd-wrap), I used the following grunt task in my Gruntfile:

```
amdwrap: {
  materialui: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'node_modules/material-ui/lib/',
    src: ['**/*.js'],
    dest: 'client/js/components/',
  },
},
```

and scheduled it to run after `material-ui` finished transpiling to its `lib` folder. However, this still poses an issue since the files `require()` the following modules:

```
"inline-style-prefixer": "^0.5.1",
"lodash.throttle": "~3.0.4",
"lodash.debounce": "~3.1.1",
"react-addons-transition-group": "^0.14.0",
"react-addons-update": "^0.14.0",
"react-addons-create-fragment": "^0.14.0",
"react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^0.14.0",
"warning": "^2.1.0"
```

And I can't figure out how to bundle those to a client-side AMD module in addition to `material-ui` itself.

In summary: Is there a way to use `grunt` to convert `material-ui`'s CommonJS syntax to a self-contained AMD module (or set of self-contained AMD modules)? I'd like to avoid using `gulp`, and I'd prefer to only use `browserify` if it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `grunt-webpack`. Although it's not an AMD module, I was able to bundle the files I needed along with their dependencies in one output file.